# Use a Foreign Key Referring to One of Two Primary Keys

Tags: sql, key

I am working on an application; one of my tables (`gamestats`) has a dual primary key, as shown below:

```
PRIMARY KEY (game_id, player_id)
```

I planned to make another table to get game types, which would have a simple structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS games 
(
    game_id integer,
    game_type_id integer,

    CONSTRAINT game_type_fk FOREIGN KEY(game_type_id) REFERENCES gamemodes(game_id)
    CONSTRAINT game_id_fk FOREIGN KEY(game_id) REFERENCES gamestats(game_id)
)
```

However, I get this error:

> There is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "gamestats"

Is it possible to have a singular foreign key reference a dual primary key? I can not include the player_id in the "games" table (there can be potentially multiple player_ids attached to the same "games" table), so is there any way I can maintain the referential integrity here?

Comment: Can you tell us what SQL Database engine you are using?

Comment: If your PK consists of two columns, then **all** referencing FK **must also** include **both columns** - you cannot reference *half a PK* - it's either all or nothing

Comment: @marc_s I see - in that case, if I turn the game_id in that table to a primary key of its own, would that be considered poor database structure?

Comment: Are you sure the foreign key shouldn't be in the other direction? I.e gamestats referencing games?